# Стилизация родительского элемента (при выборе radio-кнопки)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Привет:) Уже долго ломаю себе голову с одной проблемой, вот решил спросить у вас.
Есть блок, внутри которого расположены ещё два блока и они занимают по 50% каждый. Внутри каждого из этих блоков есть radio-кнопка. Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе radio-кнопки, менялся цвет фона у блока, в котором расположена эта кнопка. Затем, при выборе другой radio-кнопки, стиль применялся уже к ней, а с предыдущей пропадал. Получается, что необходимо обратиться к родителю и только когда radio-кнопка checked. Я не силен в JS, так что, если можно, пишите с комментариями. Извините, если вопрос сбивает с толку, и спасибо!

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #1749B3;
    border-radius: 12px;
}

.tab-switch-1 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    order: 1;
    border-radius: 12px 0px 0px 12px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    /*пример, как должна выглядеть заливка*/
    background-color: aqua;
}

.tab-switch-2 {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    order: 2;
    border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="tab-switch-1">
        <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-1" checked>
        <label for="tab-btn-1">First radio</label>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-switch-2">
        <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-2">
        <label for="tab-btn-2">Second radio</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А что попробовали вы, для достижения поставленной цели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вёрстке и желаемому вы не совсем понимаете предмет. Давайте начнём с простого. Если вы хотите стилизовать существующую html-разметку, то должны понимать, что в CSS не существует стилизации родительского элемента через детей. Для этого вам понадобится javascript. Но это не значит, что нельзя добиться того же визуального результата средствами CSS.

Упростим ваш код для понимания и попробуем реализовать?

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-1" checked>
<label for="tab-btn-1">First radio</label>

<input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-2">
<label for="tab-btn-2">Second radio</label>
```

Если вы поняли из CSS-правила `input[type="radio"]:checked + label`, то мы можем стилизовать элемент находящийся по соседству при помощи `+`.

А дальше? Можем вернуться даже к текущему html и реализовать вашу задачу. Но для этого вам понадобится `position: relative` для    и `position: absolute` для вложенных в него радио-кнопок и лабелек.

А можно пойти и другим путём, коих немало. Да вот хотя бы так:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}

label {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  color:white;
}


[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab-switch first">
    <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-btn-1">First radio</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-switch second">
    <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-2">
    <label for="tab-btn-2">Second radio</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Обычно такой эффект достигается примерно таким способом:

```js
// Находим все html элементы с именем tab-btn
const tabBtns = document.getElementsByName('tab-btn');

/*при загрузке страницы ищем элемент который выбран и устанавливаем его родителю цвет фона aqua*/

// Берем каждый найденный элемент с именем tab-btn
for (let item of tabBtns) {
  // проверяем если он выбран
  if (item.checked)
    // его родителю устанавливаем цвет фона aqua
    item.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'aqua';
}

// Берем каждый найденный элемент с именем tab-btn
for (let item of tabBtns) {
  // подписываем его на событие "изминения"
  item.addEventListener('change', e => {
    // Когда происходит изменения состояния радиокнопки
    // у всех родителей радиокнопок удаляем фон
    for (let i of tabBtns) {
      i.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }
    // На выбранной радиокнопке ее родителю
    // устанавливаем цвет фона aqua
    if (item.checked) item.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = 'aqua';
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #1749B3;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.tab-switch-1 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  order: 1;
  border-radius: 12px 0px 0px 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*пример, как должна выглядеть заливка*/
  /*background-color: aqua;*/
}

.tab-switch-2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  order: 2;
  border-radius: 0px 12px 12px 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tab-switch-1">
    <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-btn-1">First radio</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-switch-2">
    <input type="radio" name="tab-btn" id="tab-btn-2">
    <label for="tab-btn-2">Second radio</label>
  </div>
</div>
```